# Pandas - How to ignore percentages in read_excel and read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv

I have an app that allows a user to update an excel(`.xlsx`) or csv (`.csv`) file. I use `pandas.read_excel` and `pandas.read_csv` to read the files. This works great for numeric values. However when a column has `80%,` it is parsed as `0.8`. Is there a way of ignoring percentages when reading the csv or the excel files? 
So that a cell with 80% is parsed as 80 in the dataframe.

I have thought of checking if all the values in the dataframe are less than 1 but it will introduce a bug because if the user inputs zeros in the excel file (which is possible), it will be interpreted as percentage which will make it be multiplied by 100.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"? You could always correct it to be a percentage, or drop the column

Comment: I suspect that Excel actually has the value 0.8 - you've just got the column formatted to display as a percentage... but what's there is actually a float of 0.8 which is all the reader sees...

Comment: I would want a column that is 80% to be read as 80. By default it is reading it as 0.8

Comment: Make a note of the column names and multiply them after?

Comment: I can't know the column since the file is uploaded by a user. As I explained earlier, it is not possible to tell where the percentage is (by checking values less than 1) because the user may upload a file with zeros  @JonClements

Comment: Sounds like you might be able do a bit of extra work reading from Excel where you retrieving the styling applied to columns and use that as an indicator - or give the users constraints on either specifying a separate schema or rules on what format you can accept...

Comment: Are the percent signs actually in the CSV file? Or are they only displayed when you open the file in Excel?

Comment: @EliasStrehle The signs are in the xlsx file when I open it in google sheets. Pandas.read_excel reads the percentages in the csv files and converts it to decimal i.e 10% becomes 0.1 in dframe

Comment: It's not the reader that's converting it - it's physically stored as `0.1` in Excel... it's just sheets/excel has a format set for those cells which makes them display as percentages when loaded...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. Now I just have to find how to detect type of col

Comment: You need to open an instance of an openpyxl reader directly... extract the cells types to check for a format of "Percent" and then pass the sheet to the pandas reader to get what you've got, then update your frame based on the locations of cells you found.... Some info at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.6/styles.html#introduction and also you'll want to look at the `cell.number_format` attribute (I believe)

Comment: This is gold. Thank you so much

Comment: Parsing cell formats, in my opinion, may be overkill. If you have some heuristics to determine percentage columns, read as `float`, use some logic to identify percentage columns, then multiply by 100.

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores percentages as decimals. The % representation is just a "view" of the data, not a property of the underlying `float` value. If you have no knowledge of your columns beforehand, you can define some investigative logic:-

First read your file as normal (Excel or CSV):

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')  # or pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Then identify columns which are read as `float`:

```
float_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.float]).columns
```

Now filter for those columns where all values are between 0 and 1.0. This isn't watertight, since `Boolean` series will also be included. So we can add an extra condition for there to be at least *n* distinct values.

```
pct_cols = [x for x in float_cols if df[x].between(0, 1).all() and len(df[x].unique()) > 2]
```

Finally, convert decimals in range `[0, 1]` to percentages in range `[0, 100]`:

```
df[pct_cols] = df[pct_cols] * 100
```

---

Here's a complete working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.1341234, 0.563465, 1.00, 0.00, 0.456546],
                   'B': [True, False, True, True, True],
                   'C': [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]})

float_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.float]).columns
pct_cols = [x for x in float_cols if df[x].between(0, 1).all() and len(df[x].unique()) > 2]
df[pct_cols] = df[pct_cols] * 100

print(df)

           A      B    C
0   13.41234   True  1.0
1   56.34650  False  0.0
2  100.00000   True  1.0
3    0.00000   True  1.0
4   45.65460   True  0.0
```