# Read excel into pandas dataframe without modifying the values of excel?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading an xlsx file using Python's Pandas `pd.read_excel(myfile.xlsx,sheet_name="my_sheet",header=2)` and writing the df to a csv file using `df.to_csv`.

The excel file contains several columns with percentage values in it (e.g. 27.44 %). In the dataframe the values are getting converted to 0.2744, i don't want any modification in data. How can i achieve this?

I already tried:

1. using lambda function to convert back value from 0.2744 to 27.44 % but this i don't want this because the column names/index are not fixed. It can be any col  contain the % values
2. `df = pd.read_excel(myexcel.xlsx,sheet_name="my_sheet",header=5,dtype={'column_name':str})` - Didn't work
3. `df = pd.read_excel(myexcel.xlsx,sheet_name="my_sheet",header=5,dtype={'column_name':object})` - Didn't work
4. Tried xlrd module also, but that too converted % values to float.

   ```
   df = pd.read_excel(myexcel.xlsx,sheet_name="my_sheet")
   df.to_csv(mycsv.csv,sep=",",index=False)
   ```

Comment: Have a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017438/pandas-how-to-ignore-percentages-in-read-excel-and-read-csv)

Answer (score 0):

from your xlsx save the file directly in csv format

To import your csv file use pandas library as follow:

```js
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('my_sheet.csv')    #in case your file located in the same directory
```

[more information on pandas.read_csv](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-read-csv)